# missing resolution on XPS13 after upgrading to 16.10

Tags: upgrade, display-resolution, 16.10

I'm not sure if this is a bug, so i'm posting a question first so see if anyone can help me figure out it's a bug.

I just upgraded from 16.04 to 16.10 and now i'm missing a resolution mode on my XPS13-9350. I have 3200x1800 available, but i rather use 2560x1600, which was available to me while i was running 16.04.

I tried to mess a bit with xrandr, but the system froze while i was trying out stuff, so i'm not sure this is the right way.

Can anyone help me further?

Answer (score -1):

So i took some time to read some more about xrandr here;
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution#Setting_resolution_changes_in_xorg.conf_--_resolution_lower_than_expected

I finally resolved it by using the same manual, my exact steps were;

> XPS-13-9350:~$ xrandr -q
>   Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
>   eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 294mm x 165mm
>      3200x1800     59.98 +
>      2048x1536     60.00
>      1920x1440     60.00
>      1856x1392     60.01
>      1792x1344     60.01
>      1920x1200     59.95
>      1920x1080     59.93* 
>      1600x1200     60.00
>      1680x1050     59.95    59.88
>      1600x1024     60.17
>      1400x1050     59.98
>      1280x1024     60.02
>      1440x900      59.89
>      1280x960      60.00
>      1360x768      59.80    59.96
>      1152x864      60.00
>      1024x768      60.04    60.00
>      960x720       60.00
>      928x696       60.05
>      896x672       60.01
>      960x600       60.00
>      960x540       59.99
>      800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25
>      840x525       60.01    59.88
>      800x512       60.17
>      700x525       59.98
>      640x512       60.02
>      720x450       59.89
>      640x480       60.00    59.94
>      680x384       59.80    59.96
>      576x432       60.06
>      512x384       60.00
>      400x300       60.32    56.34
>      320x240       60.05
>
> XPS-13-9350:~$ cvt 2560 1440 60
>
> XPS-13-9350:~$ xrandr --newmode "2560x1440_60.00"  312.25  2560 2752 3024 3488  1440 1443 1448 1493 -hsync +vsync
>
> XPS-13-9350:~$ xrandr --addmode eDP-1 2560x1440_60.00

After that i could select the mode from the settings --> display. As you see in the lines of command, my resolution turned out to be 2560x1440 (16:9) instead of the 2560x1600 (16:10), an error on my part.